# Client-side debugging not available in Visual Studio Pro 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, javascript-debugger

This is an odd one and I'm at my wits end.

I've been using Visual Studio 2017 on my work and home PCs without issue for well over a year now (with *FAR* too many years working in previous versions to boot), but my company is now moving us to Virtual Windows 10 boxes, so I'm in the process of setting up a new Development VM.

Having installed VS 2017 Pro, I've created a quick ASP.Net Web Application (C#) directly from the template and hit F5 to Debug. The first thing I noticed was that the "Script Documents" node did not appear in the Solution Explorer, meaning I can't get to the HTML and JavaScript that's generated and sent to the browser, so I can't apply breakpoints to debug the client-side code.

I've Googled this extensively and about the only thing of relevance I've found is that last year Microsoft took the decision the turn off JavaScript debugging by default since (apparently) it's not that frequently used and leads to performance issues ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/changes-to-script-debugging-in-visual-studio-15-7/)).

I've checked the setting and ensured that JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET ***IS*** enabled, as shown below:

[image: Visual Studio Options - Debugging - General]

I've trawled through the event logs on the VM to see if there's anything in there that might shed some light on the issue, but asides from the following warnings from IIS Express (which also occur on my PC) there's nothing else.

> The directory specified for caching compressed content
>   C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool
>   is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.

I'm aware that there are other options for debugging the JavaScript, all the ones I've encountered are are both painful and slow to use - I just want to be able to debug natively in Visual Studio as I've been doing for years.

Any help would be gratefully received...

**EDIT 1: Additional Info**

The version information for Visual Studio is as follows:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017  Version 15.9.7
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.7+28307.423 Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.7.03062
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> - Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.14.20131.1
> - ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.9.04012.0
> - ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590
> - ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.60913.0
> - Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.9.03024.0
> - C# Tools   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
> - Common Azure Tools   1.10
> - Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
> - JavaScript Language Service   2.0
> - Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   2.4
> - Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
> - Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
> - Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
> - Microsoft Library Manager   1.0
> - Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
> - Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
> - NuGet Package Manager   4.6.0
> - ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
> - ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
> - SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61901.24070
> - SQL Server Reporting Services   15.0.900.163
> - TypeScript Tools   15.9.20918.2001
> - Visual Basic Tools   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
> - Visual F# Tools 10.2 for F# 4.5   15.8.0.0.  Commit Hash: 6e26c5bacc8c4201e962f5bdde0a177f82f88691.
> - Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
> - Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0

When creating the new project, the steps are as follows:

[image: New Project Dialog]

[image: Project Options]

Once the project has been created, I hit F5 to Debug and get the following (Note the lack of "Script Documents" in Solution Explorer)

[image: Debugging]

I've tried to reset all my settings, then enabled JavaScript debugging via Tools \ Options, but get the same result.

Comment: Hi, what's your vs version? please go to Help-About Microsoft Visual Studio to view. When you create the asp.net web application, which detail type did you choose like 'MVC/...', I will try to follow the detail steps to reproduce. I made some tests in my VS 2017, it seems the option "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge, and IE)" controls the Script Documents node display or not, please try: 1. go to Tools-Import and Export settings-Reset all settings, choose 'General' , check this option "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge, and IE)" 2. Repair VS 2017

Comment: Please go to Settings-Default apps-Web browser and set IE as the default one, or in VS-Web browser, choose and use another browser to have a test, it works in my side: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmFRICeKLDFlJcHHz. Meanwhile, now the latest vs version is 15.9.9, you can also try to upgrade it to test.

Comment: I've updated Visual Studio to the latest version, but alas - no joy. IE was already my default browser. I've had a brand-new VM provisioned and installed VS on that, just in case something had gone wrong with the original installation, and the same problem exists there. Could something be blocking the connection between VS & IE, like AV or some group policy restrictions?

Comment: Thanks for your detail information, how about switch another browser in VS, like Chrome?

Comment: I've just installed Chrome and to my surprise I now have a "Script Documents" node in my Solution Explorer. Stranger still, when I switch back to IE, it's still there! I'm absolutely baffled as to why installing Chrome would fix this issue. Sara - thanks so much for all your help in resolving this issue

Comment: Hi Pete, you are welcome and so glad to hear that your issue is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we need make sure the Tools-Options-Debugging-General-[Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/changes-to-script-debugging-in-visual-studio-15-7/) is checked, try to install or directly switch to other browser like Chrome to test.